# Cons of using Thread.sleep to slow down script?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This pertains to Google App Engine, using Java.
("threadsafe" in this scenario would be set to true, so please include that in your thought process.)

Which of the App Engine quotas are affected?
The goal would be to slow down some users (non-paying users), in such a way that their requests would take longer to arrive. (The time spent on the website/app is in the range of hours, per user.) So in a situation where the user is slowed down by double the wait, half of the theoretical bandwidth usage is saved, per user, since they don't spend even more time on to compensate; they go to bed at the end of the day, in this scenario.

Specifically, my goal is for this to be more cost effective, more than anything.

Are CPU quotas affected by thread delays?
(Excuse my ignorance on this topic. I assume that such a Java thread delay doesn't incur CPU usage itself, but I could be wrong, which is why I'm asking you guys, who are more knowledgeable.)

Any other things I should consider to be detrimental?

(Make sure to factor in that, in this scenario, the user themselves aren't negatively impacted by the site loading slower, and that they patiently wait for the page to load. It is the type of application where the user isn't bothered by a little bit of lag because they spend a lot of time on the site just to kill time. Hope this is understood.)

Thanks in advance for any thoughts, and thanks for at least reading my question.

Comment: I hear that Google App Engine is going to use a new billing scheme that doesn't bill purely for raw CPU time, but the amount of time your app is kept active, since it continues to occupy memory, etc. So, your approach would lose under the new system.

Comment: See http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/05/year-ahead-for-google-app-engine.html for more details.

Comment: "Instead, our serving infrastructure will charge for the number of Instances running as a new unit called “Instance-hours (IH)” (1 instance running for 1 hour)."

I'm under the impression that an Instance and a Thread are different when "threadsafe" is enabled. Of course, the service will still initiate new instances when it feels like it, so now I can't tell if this is a pro or con, since the CPU won't be the problem anymore. Confusing.

Comment: The new pricing will be a huge negative to your plan.  Currently, you also get penalized for requests taking over 1000ms.  So under new pricing you're going to be causing yourself to require more instances (which will directly translate to increased expense) and currently you're going to be harming yourself by increasing your average latency (which will cause your paying users to have increased latency since they'll be waiting on an instance to handler their request).  Doesn't sound like a good idea under the current or new pricing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the current billing model, your app will not scale up if your handlers take more than 1000ms on average to return a response. Deliberately adding sleep calls will slow your app down, and make it less likely to be autoscaled.

Under the new billing model, as Chris points out, you will be charged by instance-hours, which means that although your app will scale fine, you will pay more to slow your users down.

When most people are trying to shave milliseconds off their response times, you're asking about ways to artificially slow requests down; this seems very odd, and likely to drive your users off. Wouldn't you be better off serving them a page informing them they're over-quota and inviting them to come back later (or, say, pay you)?